# user agent stylesheet overrides table?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm doing some modifications to a wordpress theme, but I'm having a challenge removing the top border on a table. As seen in the example below, it's getting some strange details added to it:

[image: border line]

```
table {    (user agent stylesheet)
display: table;
border-collapse: separate;
border-spacing: 2px;
border-color: gray;
}
```

and then mine:

```
table {  
border: none;
border-collapse: separate;
border-spacing: 0;
border-color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

However, the strange part is that's only the top-border that is being displayed. It may be that I'm missing something here. Or, it's pretty obvious...

Example site: http://friknektene.no/wordpress/?page_id=2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `border-top` is coming from `style.css`, line 815:

```
.entry-content td,
.comment-content td {
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 6px 10px 6px 0;
}
```

As you can see, the `border-top` is being applied to a `td`, not a `table`. That's why your attempt to override isn't working.

Try this instead:

```
.entry-content td, .comment-content td {
    border-top: 0;
}
```

You may or may not want to keep `.comment-content td` in the selector above.

Comment: It might help you to know how I figured it out. I right-clicked exactly on the border, clicked "Inspect Element", and the answer was shown.